# How to read/change directories for file browsing?

Tags: php, directory

I'm having a real disconnect on how to do this--partly due to my inexperience with working with the file system. I'm trying to create a script that will navigate the folders a files below it. The file currently works by listing the contents of the directory it's in (aka "."). I'm stumped on how to make it list contents of the folders below and the best way to do it. How would my script need reworking to fit this goal?

[code]

```
// sets ordering variables
$a = $_GET['a'];

// are you allowed to delete?
if($_SESSION['delete'] == "ON") {
    $do_del = true;
    }
else {
    $do_del = false;
    }

// scandir to opendir coversion from stackoverflow.com/questions/6823489/
$files_dir = ".";
$dir_handle = opendir($files_dir);
while ($dir_temp = readdir($dir_handle)) {
    $arr_dir[] = $dir_temp;
    }
closedir($dir_handle);


// function created by "acecream" on php.net; modified to include reverse sort
function sortArray($array, $key, $reverse = false)
    {
    if(isset($array)) {
        foreach ($array as $i => $k)
            { $sort_values[$i] = $array[$i][$key]; }

        if ($reverse == true)
            { arsort ($sort_values); }
        else
            { asort ($sort_values); }
        reset ($sort_values);

        while (list ($arr_key, $arr_val) = each ($sort_values))
            { $sorted_arr[] = $array[$arr_key]; }

        return $sorted_arr;
        }
    }


foreach($arr_dir as $file)
    {
    if(!preg_match("/(_vti)|(_borders)|(_private)|(hidden)|(~_)|(\.php)/", $file) && ($file != ".") && ($file !=".."))
        {
        $full   = "$files_dir/$file";

        $name   = strval($file);
        $size   = sprintf("%u", filesize($full));
        $kind   = pathinfo($file, PATHINFO_EXTENSION); // strval(end(explode(".", $file)));
        $mtime  = filemtime($full); // modify date
        $ctime  = filectime($full); // creation date

        $arr_files[] = array($name, $size, $kind, $mtime, $ctime);
        }
    }
$arr_count = count($arr_files);

switch ($a) {
    case 1 : $arr_files = sortArray($arr_files, 0); break;
    case 2 : $arr_files = sortArray($arr_files, 0, true); break;
    case 3 : $arr_files = sortArray($arr_files, 1); break;
    case 4 : $arr_files = sortArray($arr_files, 1, true); break;
    case 5 : $arr_files = sortArray($arr_files, 2); break;
    case 6 : $arr_files = sortArray($arr_files, 2, true); break;
    case 7 : $arr_files = sortArray($arr_files, 3); break;
    case 8 : $arr_files = sortArray($arr_files, 3, true); break;
    default: $arr_files = sortArray($arr_files, 3, true); break;
    }
unset($a);

function myFileSize($value) {
    // convert raw byte site to friendlier forms
    if($value > 1000)       { $sizestr = round(($value/1024), 1) . " KB"; }
        else                { $sizestr = "$value B"; }
    if($value > 1000000)    { $sizestr = round(($value/1048576), 1) . " MB"; }
    if($value > 1000000000) { $sizestr = round(($value/1073741824), 1) . " GB"; }
    return $sizestr;
    }
function myDate($value) {
    $date = date("j M y G:i", $value);
    return $date;
    }

if($arr_count > 0)
    {
    if($do_del == true) {
        print "<form method=\"post\" action=\"./?d=delete\">\n";
        }
        print "<table>\n";
        print "     <tr>\n";
        print "         <td>File Name</td>\n";
        print "         <td>Size</td>\n";
        print "         <td>Type</td>\n";
        print "         <td>Modified</td>\n";
        print "         <td>Created</td>\n";
    if($do_del == true) {
        print "         <td>Delete?</td>\n";
        }
        print "     </tr>\n";
        print "     <tr style=\"vertical-align: middle; background-color: #fff; border: 1px solid #000;\">\n";
        print "         <td>\n";
        print "             <a href=\"./?a=1\"><img src=\"./~_arr-asc.gif\" border=\"0\"></a>\n";
        print "             <a href=\"./?a=2\"><img src=\"./~_arr-dsc.gif\" border=\"0\"></a>\n";
        print "         </td>\n";
        print "         <td>\n";
        print "             <a href=\"./?a=3\"><img src=\"./~_arr-asc.gif\" border=\"0\"></a>\n";
        print "             <a href=\"./?a=4\"><img src=\"./~_arr-dsc.gif\" border=\"0\"></a>\n";
        print "         </td>\n";                       
        print "         <td>\n";
        print "             <a href=\"./?a=5\"><img src=\"./~_arr-asc.gif\" border=\"0\"></a>\n";
        print "             <a href=\"./?a=6\"><img src=\"./~_arr-dsc.gif\" border=\"0\"></a>\n";
        print "         </td>\n";
        print "         <td>\n";
        print "             <a href=\"./?a=7\"><img src=\"./~_arr-asc.gif\" border=\"0\"></a>\n";
        print "             <a href=\"./?a=8\"><img src=\"./~_arr-dsc.gif\" border=\"0\"></a>\n";
        print "         </td>\n";
        print "         <td>&nbsp;</td>\n";
    if($do_del == true) {
        print "         <td>&nbsp;</td>\n";
        }
        print "     </tr>\n";

    for ($beat = 0; $beat < $arr_count; $beat++)
        {
        $name   = $arr_files[$beat][0];
        $size   = $arr_files[$beat][1];
        $ext    = strtolower($arr_files[$beat][2]);
        $mdate  = $arr_files[$beat][3];
        $cdate  = $arr_files[$beat][4];

        $size   = myFileSize($size);
        $mdate  = myDate($mdate);
        $cdate  = myDate($cdate);

        // pick the image for file type based on file extension
        if(is_dir($name)) {
            $pic = "~_folder.png";
            }
        else {
            $pic = "~_file.png";
            }


        $url  = "<a href=\"$files_dir/$name\">$name</a>";   // create hard link

            print " <tr>\n";
            print "     <td style=\"width: 300px;\"><img src=\"./$pic\"> $url</td>\n";
            print "     <td style=\"width:  75px;\">$size</td>\n";
            print "     <td style=\"width:  50px;\">$ext</td>\n";
            print "     <td style=\"width: 150px;\">$mdate</td>\n";
            print "     <td style=\"width: 150px;\">$cdate</td>\n";
        if($do_del == true) {
            print "     <td><input type=\"checkbox\" name=\"list[$files_dir/$name]\" value=\"ON\"></td>\n";
            }
        print " </tr>\n";
        }
    print "</table>\n";

    if($do_del == true) {
        print " <p><input name=\"Submit1\" type=\"submit\" value=\"submit\">\n";
        print " <input name=\"Reset1\" type=\"reset\" value=\"reset\"></p>\n";
        print "</form>\n";
        }
    }
else
    {
    print "There are no files available for download.";
    }
```

[/code]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make your script a function that takes in the path.

Then in the while statement inside if(is_dir($file)) call your function and pass it $file.

For example,

```
function myFileSize($value) {...}
function myDate($value) {...}

function list_contents($path)
{
    $dir_name = $path;
    .
    .
    .
    $dir = opendir($path);
    .
    .
    .
    while ($file = readdir($dir)) {
        // do some stuff
        if (is_dir($file)) {
            list_contents($file);
        }
    }
}
```

Depending on what you want to do you will need to modify the output of the list_contents() function to work with the recursion. You could generate some tree structure using an array and then print the tree out later like:

```
// return an array representing tree structure
function list_contents($path, &$tree)
{
    // ...
    while ($file = readdir($dir)) {
        $tree[$path][] = $file;
        if (is_dir($file)) {
            list_contents($file, $tree[$path]);
        }
    }

    return $tree;
}

function print_tree($tree)
{
    // code to display array using tree structure
}

$path = '.';
$dir_name = $path;

$tree_array = array();
$tree = list_contents($path, $tree_array)

print_tree($tree);
```

Or you could add a variable to count the number of levels in the method is

```
function list_contents($path, $level = 0)
{
    //...
    // indent output text by $level number of tabs
    while($file = readdir($dir) {
        if (is_dir($file)) {
            list_contents($file, $level++)
        }
    }
}

list_contents($path);
```

Output would look something like

```
> Root
    > Folder1 in root
    > Folder2 in root
        > Folder1 in Folder2
        > Folder2 in Folder2
    > Folder3 in root
        > Folder1 in Folder3
              > Folder1 in Folder1/Folder3
        > File1 in Folder1
    > File1 in root
    > File2 in root
```

As a suggestion, I would take any functions related to getting file information or manipulating files and put them in their own file file_functions.php and then include that at the top of your script.